# how to generate two random arrays in c

Tags: arrays, c

I want to generate two random arrays
no matter what i tried but the two tables are always identical

```
double *init_rand_w(double tableau[],int tailleTableau) {
    //double *tableau=malloc(tailleTableau*sizeof(double));
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0 ; i < tailleTableau ; i++)
    {

        tableau[i]=((double)rand())/((double)RAND_MAX);
    }

    return  tableau;
}

int main()
{
    double *t1=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*10);
    double *t2=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*10);

    t1=init_rand_w(t1,5);
    t2=init_rand_w(t2,5);

    shuffle(t2,5);

    printf("***************************\n");

    for (int x = 0; x <5; x++)
    {
        printf("%f  ,  %f \n", t1[x],t2[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `srand` twice.  Your loops certainly run fast enough that your two calls to `srand` happen in the same second, so `time()` returns the same value.

Comment: Call `srand(time(NULL));` once at the beginning of your program.

Comment: thank you guys it works

Answer (score 1):

You should just call `srand` once at the beginning of your program.  It initializes the state of the random number generator.  You are currently calling it twice, and you are likely giving it the same seed value each time you call it (since your program would take a lot less than one second to run), so you would get the same sequence of random numbers.